# Count number of buses to yield given waiting time

Tags: word-problem

I'm sorry if my question sounds like beginner. My friends asked me this question and I was a bit confused with this.

> Suppose there are four stations in a 60 km loop. If bus speed is 12 km/h how many buses are needed so that the waiting time is *at most* 5 minutes?

Can this problem be solved? Or does the problem need more detail to be added? Maybe such as time intervals between buses

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes five hours for one bus to complete a loop around the four stations. To make the waiting time five minutes you would thus need (5 hours / 5 minutes) = **60** buses.

Comment: I also think so, but will the 60 buses make each station's waiting time to 5 minutes? I mean 60 buses for full loop right? how about for each station ? (a to b,b to c etc)
Does the question not require bus departure information?

Comment: @boy It does not matter where the stations are along the loop. With 60 buses plying the route the waiting time will be 5 minutes anywhere!

Comment: Nice, thanks for the information!

Comment: @boy If you don't know yet you can upvote and accept answers. Click the green tick below my answer and the up button above the zero.

Comment: yup i've done that

Comment: @boy But you haven't done them to my answer!

Comment: actually the waiting time will be *at most* five minutes anywhere.  If all four stations are situated one minute apart then to obtain a strict 5 minutes they'd have to wait for four minutes half-way between each station and you'll need a few extra buses to compensate.